Gauss-Bonnet Theorem on $T^2$
Consider the 2-dimensional torus $T^2$. Like picture below, the curve $L$ divide the 2-torus to two parts $A_1, A_2$. And, the orientation of $L$ is shown by the arrow.
Denote the sectional curvature as $K$. I think  the Gauss-Bonnet theorem imply
$$
\iint_{A_1} K d\mu + \int_L k_g ds = 2\pi 
\tag{1}
$$
Since $$
\iint _{T^2} Kd\mu  =2\pi \chi(T^2) =0
\tag{2}
$$
I have $$
\iint_{A_2} K d\mu  - \int_L k_g ds = -2\pi
\tag{3}
$$
Is there any problem with the above calculation?




Your calculation is fine.
But I'll point out something interesting that is going on here: your third equation should be no surprise because it is the same as the Gauss-Bonnet theorem for the surface $A_2$. Here's why.
Given a smooth curve in a 2-manifold and a point on that curve, geodesic curvature is only well defined after you choose one of the two normal directions of that curve. Furthermore, there are two choices of the normal direction, and opposite choices give geodesic curvatures that are negatives of each other. In your first equation, in the geodesic curvature term $\iint_L k_g ds$, your function $k_g$ represents the geodesic curvature in the normal direction that points towards $A_1$. Therefore, $-k_g$ represents the geodesic curvature in the normal direction that points towards $A_2$. But that means $\iint_L (-k_g) ds = - \iint_L k_g ds$ is equal to the geodesic curvature term for the surfae $A_2$.
Also, the Euler characteristic of $A_2$ is $-1$. But that means that $(-1) \cdot 2\pi = -2\pi$ should be the right hand side of the Gauss-Bonnet theorem for $A_2$, as it is in your third equation.
